# How to calculate max,min, avg values with for loop taking user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a Python homework question asking the user to input the number of times they will run around the track and then use a For Loop to prompt them to enter the time for each lap. When the loop is finished, the program will display the fastest, slowest and the average lap time.

The calculation of the average is easy to do with just For Loop as I just need to add up the lap time with '+=' then dividing the number of loops but not sure how to store the individual values with the For Loop to store and retrieve the max (slowest) and min (fastest) values.

I've tried using a list to perform this:

```
lap_time = float(input('Enter the lap times separated by space'))

time = lap_time.separator()
fastest = min[time]
slower = max[time]
```

However when I tried average(time), it gave an error stating that the list values are non numeric.

p.s. also tried import statistics to use the mean function but got the same error.

Greatly appreciated if anyone can give me some guidance on this question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the sample inputs as well?

Comment: `float` can convert only one numer in string. You have to split text in separated "words" and convert every "word" to number. For you It can be easier to ask for every number separtelly in `for` loop, convert to float and append to list.

Answer (score 0):

Not the clearest answer but it will help you understand what to do **and that's most importand here** (Edit.: As it is homework)

```
timeMAX = 0#slowest
timeMIN = 0#fastest
for #yourForLoop
    if sys.stdin.readline() > timeMAX:
        timeMAX = sys.stdin.readline()
    if sys.stdin.readline() < timeMIN:
        timeMIN = sys.stdin.readline()
```

For better readability I'd use `time=sys.stdin.readline()`. Remember to make sure that users answer can be less than zero or character. GL!

Answer (score 0):

you can map each values to float after splitting

```
lap_time = list(map(float, input('Enter the lap times separated by space : ').split()))
print(lap_time)
fastest = max(lap_time)
slower = min(lap_time)
average  = sum(lap_time) / len(lap_time)
print('Fastest:{} ,Slowest :{} ,Average:{}'.format(fastest,slower,average))
```

input :-
`Enter the lap times separated by space :` `10 20 30 40 50`
output :-

```
[10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0]
Fastest:50.0 ,Slowest :10.0 , Average:30.0
```

Comment: Hello Shijith, I tried but it is throwing back error:  ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: @alexlaw888, this error is because your `lap_time` variable which is supposed to hold a list of float values is empty. enter the lap times separated by space when it asks for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using (I also do `average`):

```
lap_time = map(float, input('Enter the lap times separated by space').split())

fastest = min(lap_time)
slower = max(lap_time)
average = sum(lap_time) / len(lap_time)
```

Comment: This program does not work on Python3 (nor on Python2 for different reason). The result of `map` is an iterator and can be used only once. Then it is exhausted (empty).

Answer (score 0):

Some errors in your code

- You need to take in the input of laps as a string, you are taking the input as a float, which won't work here
- We use `string.split` to split a string to whitespaces, we don't have a function called `separator` for that
- `max` and `min` are functions which will take the list as an argument like `min(arr)` or `max(arr)`
- You can calculate the average by taking the sum of the list by doing `sum(arr)` and dividing it by number of items in the list

A refactored code will then be

```
#Get input as string
s = input('Enter the lap times separated by space')

lap_time = []
#Split string on whitespace, convert each string to float and save to laptime string
for item in s.split():
    lap_time.append(float(item))

#Calculate fastest and slowest by min and max function
fastest = min(lap_time)
slowest = max(lap_time)

#Calculate average by divinding sum of lap times by no of items in list
average = sum(lap_time)/len(lap_time)

print('Fastest ', fastest)
print('Slowest ', slowest)
print('Average ', average)
```

The output will be

```
Enter the lap times separated by space1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
Fastest  1.0
Slowest  5.0
Average  3.0
```

Note here that I can also reduce the size of the code to make it more compact, but that takes away the learning from the code for a beginner!